# gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction in local permissioned Node

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, quorum

I am facing the some issue with gas but i do not have any modifiers in my contract. Even a simple setter-getter contract shows the following Error

> Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

- The above error is displayed when i try to estimateGas for setting a value for the string variable using setter().
- If i directly execute the transaction without estimateGas then i get a transaction Hash. when transaction is checked the transaction status is as follows

> 0x0 Transaction mined but execution failed

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract SampleContract{
    string public str;
    constructor()public{
        str="Hello World!"; 
    }
    function setter(string memory s)public{
        str=s;  
    }
}
```

[image]

> **Note: Contract Deployed directly in Geth-Console of locally created Node**
>
> - Using Private Permissioned Node ***Quorum (v 2.4.0)***
> - ***Solc*** to compile and generate abi and bytecode

Can anyone please solve my issue.

Comment: This seems to work on my instance of Quorum's 7node example. Can you provide your genesis and startup params for the node?

Comment: `homesteadBlock": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"chainId": 10,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"eip158Block": 0,
"isQuorum": true`

Comment: I am able to interact with the contracts deployed using Remix browser but i am not able to generate address if deployed by Geth console and if address is generated then shows gas issue when interacted. I always face either of these issues.

Comment: I am getting this error when calling and storing string values, in case of uint, calling doesn't show error but storing shows the same error 

**Error while calling a string value :  BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number:**

Comment: When in doubt, please use 7nodes genesis. Looks like you are missing constantinopleBlock. Please use this: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/blob/master/examples/7nodes/genesis.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"byzantiumBlock": 0,
"chainId": 10,
"eip150Block": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"eip158Block": 0,
"isQuorum": true,
"maxCodeSize": 128,
"txnSizeLimit": 128
```

Using the above config  values in genesis.json helped me deploy contracts of larger size.

for latest versions of quorum use the below code

```
  "homesteadBlock": 0,
  "byzantiumBlock": 0,
  "chainId": 10,
  "eip150Block": 0,
  "eip155Block": 0,
  "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "eip158Block": 0,
  "isQuorum": true,
  "maxCodeSizeConfig": [
     {
      "block": 0,
      "size": 128
     }
  ],
  "txnSizeLimit": 128
```